# clock_gettime performance regression

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am running the following bench to measure the time it takes to make a call to

`clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID)`:

```
 struct timespec start, end;
  int nb_rep = 1E6;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
  for (int i = 0; i < nb_rep; i++) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
  uint64_t ellapsed = (end.tv_sec * 1E9 + end.tv_nsec) - (start.tv_sec * 1E9 + start.tv_nsec);
  printf("Time for clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID) = %" PRIu64 " nanoseconds (ellapsed = %ld)\n", ellapsed / nb_rep, ellapsed);
```

I am running my bench using `sudo taskset -c 2 chrt -f 1 ./bench` and got the following results (my distrib is Ubunut 14.10):

- kernel 3.13 **650** nanoseconds
- kernel 3.11 **135** nanoseconds

I can't explain these differences and was wondering if it could come from kernel code changes ? Which direction should I take to identify the origin of this change ?

Here is the output of perf record/report for kernel 3.11

```
12.21%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __ticket_spin_lock         
10.09%  cache_tests  [vdso]             [.] 0x00000000000007d2         
 6.78%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
 6.74%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] task_sched_runtime         
 6.71%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] copy_user_generic_string   
 5.77%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_read_tsc            
 5.47%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] system_call                
 4.81%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] system_call_after_swapgs
```

and here for kernel 3.13

```
23.83%  cache_tests  [vdso]             [.] 0x00000000000007c2            
 5.49%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __acct_update_integrals       
 5.38%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] context_tracking_user_exit    
 4.26%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] _raw_spin_lock                
 4.24%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] local_clock                   
 4.04%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] sched_clock_cpu               
 3.74%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_eqs_enter_common.isra.47  
 3.41%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_read_tsc               
 3.21%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_eqs_exit_common.isra.48   
 2.90%  cache_tests  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_sched_clock
```

How can I interpret that ?

Comment: Can you do profiling with `perf record` (may be with -g option)? It will profile kernel too.

Comment: @osgx thanks. i updated the question with perf record/report output, but I am not sure about how interpret the results

Comment: Replace with output from `perf report -n` please, and with more lines, around 50-100. What is your CPU? How the 3.11 kernel was compiled, is the 3.11 config similar to config of 3.13? Are there ubuntu patches?

Comment: The biggest change appears to be the code in the VDSO page, which perf does not show. Isn't that just a simple system call?